# Injecting scripts via blob is advisable?

Tags: javascript, blob, web-worker

Am trying to download the javascript files through web workers by using XHR and injecting to body via blob URL. Is it advisable of doing it ?

Sample code:

```
var worker = "https://wrapperbi.com/worker/worker.js";
            let scriptWrappers = 'importScripts(\'' + worker + '\')', //No I18N
            workerPaths = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([scriptWrappers])),
            dataObj = {'responseType':'blob', 'requestURL': "https://wrapperbi.com/js/manifest.js"};
            let assetsWorkerss = new Worker(workerPaths);
            assetsWorkerss.postMessage(dataObj);
            assetsWorkerss.onmessage = function (event) {

                var script = document.createElement('script'),
                    src = URL.createObjectURL(event.data);

                script.src = src;
                document.body.appendChild(script);
```

worker file sample code:

```
onmessage = function (event) {

        var requestType = event.data.requestType ? event.data.requestType : 'GET',
            isAsync = typeof event.data.isAsync === "undefined" ? true : event.data.isAsync,
            responseType = event.data.responseType ? event.data.responseType : 'json',
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open(requestType, event.data.requestURL, isAsync);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
                        postMessage(this.response);
                }
        };

        xhr.onerror = function () {
                postMessage(this.status);
        };

        xhr.responseType = responseType;

        if(event.data.isCrossDomain) {
                xhr.withCredentials = event.data.isCrossDomain;
        }

        xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Sounds right to me, consider a framework that pre-bundles a bunch of scripts in an archive and extracts them in the browser. window.URL.createObjectURL should enforce all the regular cors/security magic, but it's probably not as secure on some browsers. The question is why? Can't imagine a situation where this can't be solved better in other ways.

Comment: Why that complicated path exactly? Why use Workers for network requests? Why the use of a Blob generated Worker here? Without knowing why you do that it's hard to tell if it's advisable or not. It's like asking us of it's advisable to build the string `"foo"` with 25 calls to different functions that would en up doing `"f" +"o"+"o"`. Not really advisable no, unless you have a good reason to do so. Note that you are creating a memory leak (a few kb but still): a never revoked blobURI will keep the Blob in memory.